# A shoe in the safe

Tags: lateral-thinking

A woman travels often, and when she does, she stays in hotels. Every night, before going to bed in a hotel, she takes off her shoes and puts one of the shoes into the hotel safe.

Why?

Comment: Because she doesn't want to sleepwalk in a hotel ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possible Reasoning

> This ensures she will remember to check the hotel safe before leaving the room in case she has stored any valuables in there. It's common for people to forget to check the safe before they leave but the necessary retrieval of the shoe forces this.

Comment: and she has only one pair of shoes / she plans to wear the same when leaving

Answer (score 3):

> Because she is a frequent traveler, often staying in unfamiliar hotels, she keeps a reserve of money in the heel of one of her shoes and, being a sound sleeper (or maybe needing to take sleeping pills to ensure a sound sleep in unfamiliar surroundings), takes the precaution of putting this shoe in the hotel safe.

Answer (score -1):

Alternate:

> She often gets lonely, but is also lazy, so every night she calls the Front Desk to ask someone to please come up and unlock her safe; she can't possibly walk down to the Front Desk herself, as her shoe is locked in the safe.

Comment: "Can't possibly"?? I don't know about the hotels *you* choose to stay in, but none of the ones where I've ever stayed have burning coals for carpet... ;-)

Comment: I have a friend who managed to lock himself out of his room when he was naked. It was in Australia, so the clerk at reception just said "not a problem, sir. Happens all the time." The large number of people in the bar fell into silence as he crossed the lobby though.

Comment: … which they do each of the many times this happens all the time.